# install MongoDB on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am  follow this step but not working for ubuntu 22.04.

```
echo "* Installing Mongod..."
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list

sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Comment: What does this mean? "but not working for ubuntu 22.04"

Answer (score 5):

I installed it in the following way:

## Step 1/2: Installation of libssl1.1

###### download library

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

###### install it

```
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

## Step 2/2: Installation of mongodb

Following the official mongodb installion page https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

The operation should respond with an OK.

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
```

```
sudo apt update
```

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Mongodb is now installed.

To start mongodb: `sudo systemctl start mongod`.
To verify that MongoDB has started successfully: `sudo systemctl status mongod`

Comment: Step 1: Error 404, not found

Comment: Hi @Lee Morgan, the package is no longer available on the old link, you can find it on the page http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl. Download it, then install it and continue with step 2.
If you can't find it, then try this link http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.0l-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable**

**Steps to install mongodb in ubuntu 22.04**

1. First of all update  system packages

`sudo apt update`

2. Download libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

3. Install the above using the dpkg command

`sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

4. Install required packages

`sudo apt install wget curl gnupg2 software-properties-common apt-transport-https ca-certificates lsb-release`

5. Add the MongoDB GPG key to apt

`wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

6. Create a file called mongodb-org-5.0.list. To download and install the sources of the target packages

`echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list`

7. Update  system packages again

`sudo apt update`

8. Install MongoDB on your system

`sudo apt install mongodb-org -y`

9. Start the MongoDB service

`sudo systemctl start mongod`

10. Check MongoDB status

`sudo systemctl status mongod`

11. Enable the MongoDB database. This is for running even after rebooting.

`sudo systemctl enable mongod`

12. For accessing mongodb shell

`mongo`

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libssl1.1

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list

sudo apt-get install gnupg curl
curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-4.4.asc | \
sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-4.4.gpg \
 --dearmor

 echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-4.4.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.4.24 mongodb-org-server=4.4.24 mongodb-org-shell=4.4.24 mongodb-org-mongos=4.4.24 mongodb-org-tools=4.4.24

 sudo service mongod start

 sudo service mongod status
```

Comment: This solution works but libssl1.1 is an old package and may likely had vulnerabilities. The message from the mongoDB team is for you to wait for them to release the updates for ubuntu 22.04. 
Here is the official response: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-over-ubuntu-22-04/159931/6#:~:text=Hi%20folks%2C,validate%20new%20packages.

Comment: E: Package 'libssl1.1' has no installation candidate

Answer (score -2):

**Finally! Below Solutions worked for me**

It is because of the missing dependencies mongodb not installing on ubuntu 22.04.
The main reason is the missing of libssl1.1 dependency. So we need to install it seperately.

1.`sudo apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common`

2.`echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list`

3.Go to root user `sudo -i`  then paste this `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

4.`apt update`

5.`apt install libssl1.1`

6.`wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

7.`echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list`

8.`apt update`

9.`apt install -y mongodb-org`

**The latest version of mongodb will be installed**
To start it

1.`systemctl enable mongod`

2.`systemctl start mongod`

In case MongoDB doesn’t start run the command below to reload.

`systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: E: Package 'libssl1.1' has no installation candidate