# Mongodb installation issue on ubuntu 22.04 Jammy - repo.mongodb.org not found

Tags: mongodb

I am exhausted all the ideas for a simple installation of MongoDB inside by Ubuntu 22.04 containers :

I have followed below steps and official steps :
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
[install MongoDB on ubuntu 22.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72516987/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-22-04)

No matter what I do I have failure to connect on repo.mongodb.org .

```
root@62388d67ab12:/# echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse
root@62388d67ab12:/# sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease
Ign:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease
Ign:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease
Err:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease
  Could not connect to repo.mongodb.org:443 (18.155.173.118), connection timed out Could not connect to repo.mongodb.org:443 (18.155.173.11), connection timed out Could not connect to repo.mongodb.org:443 (18.155.173.63), connection timed out Could not connect to repo.mongodb.org:443 (18.155.173.96), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/5.0/InRelease  Could not connect to repo.mongodb.org:443 (18.155.173.118), connection timed out Could not connect to repo.mongodb.org:443 (18.155.173.11), connection timed out Could not connect to repo.mongodb.org:443 (18.155.173.63), connection timed out Could not connect to repo.mongodb.org:443 (18.155.173.96), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find solution hence solved that problem with building mongodb 7 from the source to the container using the ubuntu 22.04 image and using the instruction below :

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/building.md